# How to show all my private Google Photos on a map?

Tags: google-photos

Sometimes I remember places but not the time when I have taken a photo. Thus it would be super helpful to have all my Google Photos available on a map with location.

Then I could go to a certain place (on Google maps) that I have visited, and see the photos I have taken there.

This is especially helpful if I cannot remember the time I took the photo - and cannot find it anymore.

Is there any way I can display my private photos on a map?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this answer is what you are looking for and not too simplistic. When you are in the home screen of Google Photos, make sure you are clicked on Photos and not Albums. In the search box type in the name of the place you want to view all your past photos. For instance if you type in New York it should bring up all your photos that were taken in New York irrespective of when they were taken. The Info screen for each photo will have a small section of Google Maps with a red marker showing where the photo was taken.
This can only happen if the photo was taken using a device that has a GPS tracker that adds the GPS coordinates to each photo. For instance a modern smart phone.
If you have older photos where the GPS coordinates were not embedded in the photo you can add the location manually by selecting a photo's Info and typing in the location, where Google asks "Where Was This Taken?". This is not quite as simple as it seems as the street name is not usually enough, instead you need to choose a nearby landmark or company name that appears on Google Maps. Then Google Photos will recognise it. The location may be a couple of hundred yards from where the photo was taken, but hey, most people can live with that.
This can be laborious but once you are up to date with your data all manner of searches can be carried out. Google can even recognise objects within your photos. Just try typing an object's name into the search box and see where it takes you.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is: "How to show **all** my private Google Photos on **one** map?"